# Proof that a boundary of a cuboid is a zero-volume set

Tags: general-topology, lebesgue-measure

Let $ I $ be a cuboid in $ \mathbb{R}^n $.

We say that a set is of volume-zero, if for any $ \varepsilon> 0 $ there exists a finite number of cuboids $ I_1,\ldots,I_k $ such that

$$ \sum_{j=1}^k \operatorname{vol}(I_j)<\varepsilon, \qquad \text{and} \qquad A\subseteq\bigcup_{j=1}^{k}\text{int}(I_{j}) $$

where $ \operatorname{int}(I_j)$ denotes the interior of $I_j$

Now how can I prove that the boundary of a cuboid $ I $ is a zero-volume set?

I already proved that a **compact** set is of measure zero if and only if the set is of volume zero, so a proof that a boundary of a cuboid is a set of measure-zero would also be helpful.
(The definition I know for measure-zero set is the same as for volume-zero set that I mentioned here except that we allow the cover to be countable and not just finite).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The closure of a cuboid? It's not. Any set with non-empty interior has positive volume. Do you mean the boundary?

Comment: @TedShifrin Im sorry, Indeed, I ment the boundary. Editing.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Didnt ment to challenge the definition of volume from  elementary geometry, just language difficulties.

Comment: Hints: Prove it for the ball $\rm{B}(0,1)$ first. Use the translation invariant and scaing properties of the measure in question to prove this for all balls. Then extend to general sets (you can cover any set you like with countably many such balls (why?)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let your cuboid be $\prod_{i=1}^n[a_i,b_i]$. Then, its boundary is covered by $2n$ cuboid interiors:

$$X_i=(a_i-\delta, a_i+\delta)\times\prod_{j=1,j\ne i}^n(a_j-\delta,b_j+\delta)$$
$$Y_i=(b_i-\delta, b_i+\delta)\times\prod_{j=1,j\ne i}^n(a_j-\delta,b_j+\delta)$$

for $i=1,\ldots,n$. The volume of each of those interiors converges to $0$ as $\delta\to 0$:

$$\operatorname{vol}(X_i)=\operatorname{vol}(Y_i)=2\delta\prod_{j=1,j\ne i}^n(b_j-a_j+2\delta)$$

Thus, the (finite) sum of all those volumes also converges to $0$ as $\delta\to 0$. This means that the sum on the left-hand side of your definition of "volume zero" we can (by choosing suitably small $\delta$) make arbitrarily small (smaller than any pre-determined $\varepsilon>0$).

**The intuition** here is: to prove the boundary of a rectangle is of area $0$, we cover each side of the rectangle with *very thin* rectangles (of thickness $2\delta$), which "just" cover the sides. Then we let $\delta\to 0$.

[image]